# Visual Studio Tools for Cordova, Xcode 10 & emulators

Tags: xcode, cordova, visual-studio-2017, ios-simulator, taco

Is VS-TACO actually still supported? Looking at the documentation, it all still refers to Xcode 8.x whereas my understanding is that all iOS apps destined for the Apple/iTunes store must be built with Xcode 10+. I also note that there does not seem to have been any "official" responses to [issues on their GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues) for quite some time.

Anyway, I am trying to get VS-TACO configured correctly with my MAC so that I can run/debug in the simulators on the MAC, however whenever I try to do this the request for the simulator returns a 404 error...

On the PC (VS Output Window)…

> Requesting emulate on iOS Simulator for buildNumber 22541 on server http://martin-macmini.home:3000/cordova...
>
> http://martin-macmini.home:3000/cordova/build/22541/emulate?target=iPhone+6+Plus The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>
> Requesting debug on remote iOS device for buildNumber 22541 on server http://martin-macmini.home:3000/cordova...
>
> Debugging - Successfully Debugging on the device {webDebugPort=9221}
>
> Timed out connecting debugger to remote Apache Cordova app. See Output window for JavaScript console output.
>
> We were unable to find the app you’re trying to debug. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked. Also, make sure it has Web Inspector enabled.

On the MAC (Terminal Window running "remotebuild -- secure false")…

> GET /cordova/build/22541/emulate?target=iPhone+6+Plus 404 1109.681ms - 1447
>
> GET /cordova/build/22541/debug 200 263.998ms - 1100

I have confirmed that the simulator will start by navigating to the uploaded project and running it in the simulator via Xcode and I have spent over a day looking at various solutions online - none of which seem to work...

- Tried installing the latest version of Cordova and selecting it (Global Cordova 8.1.0) within the config.xml; this just leads to different errors (The "VsTac" task failed unexpectedly. Could not find file '...\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz')
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide?view=toolsforcordova-2017#xcode8
- https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues

FYI: Windows 10 Professional 1803 (17134.285), VS2017 (15.8.5), Cordova toolset 6.3.1 (also tried global 8.1.0), macOS High Sierra (10.13.6), Xcode 10.0 (10A255)

Answer (score 0):

The more you update Cordova, Xcode and anything else for the matter, the **more errors** you'll get from Visual Studio. Remember that VS2017 was released with Cordova 6.x in mind, the second you implement a newer Cordova version [things will go wrong for VS2017](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/).

I gave up on the remote agent long ago, and instead **created a mirrored copy of the project in the Mac** using latest Cordova 8 and Xcode 9, following the [instructions detailed here](https://www.andreszsogon.com/build-cordova-ios-app-from-visual-studio-for-windows/). I know this is not as straightforward as the remoteagent method, but it actually works and will (surely) keep working with future Cordova and Xcode versions.